# How to calculate an number of hours from items by using dynamic actions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm developing a new field ion oracle apex which calculates the number of hours using date pickers in oracle Apex 19. When the Time is changed, it should calculate the new number of hours and displays it in a display only field.

When the Time is changed, it should calculate the new number of hours and displays it in a display only field. I tried a dynamic action which calculates it with the entered/selected value when the date picker is changed.

I have tried this so far.

```
select
to_char(TRUNC((:P2_ENDE - :P2_BEGINN)*24,2)) || ' h'
from dual
;
```

So if I would enter a Time Span from 8 am to 6 pm I would wait 10 hours. At the moment it only displays "h" without a number.
[[image: Items in Page Designer[1]]
[image: Date Picker in Application]
[image: current result in Application]

Comment: How have you defined the 'dynamic action'? All you've shown is a query; is that part of a trigger, or something else? (Also 06:14 to 18:14 is 12 hours, but with the dates you've picked the results would be 252 hours, right? And 8am to 6pm is 10 hours, not 8.)

Comment: in this example I have it defined as:   when end is changed execute the sql code.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected my 8 to 6 false.  It only should claculate the difference for each day, like if 8 am and 6 pm is selected for 5 days. I have 5 days from 8am to 6pm which makes 10 hours a day :) @Alex Poole

Comment: As someone mentioned in a comment, if you're calculating the amount of hours by using the fields in the page, unless you submit them, or use a javascript process to set the session state (which can be iffy considering asynchronicity), it won't work. The best idea would be to either submit the page to have the value calculated, or already calculate it without necessarily needing the fields to be set, maybe with a javascript function that gets the values that were selected and then calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

did you submit the page items :P2_ENDE, :P2_BEGINN. if did submit them and didnt work, please demonstrate your issue in apex.oracle.com